# How do I convert an NSString value to NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

How do I convert an `NSString` value to `NSData`?

Answer (score 1447):

```
NSString* str = @"teststring";
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: What are the pros and cons of using UTF-8 as opposed to something higher like UTF-16 or UTF-32?

Comment: The NSData doesn't care much about whether it is UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32. There are two problems: One, UTF-16 and UTF-32 need to have the right byte-ordering. Two, whoever converts it back to an NSString* must know the encoding, and often will assume UTF-8 encoding. Generally, UTF-8 is most likely to be handled correctly.

Comment: @bendytree actually no it doesn't, -dataUsingEncoding: will return an non-null-terminated string which is what stringWithUTF8String: requires, you're bounds to read memory you don't want. What converts it back is: -initWithData:encoding:.

Comment: @Albert Renshaw currently (no guarantee of things staying this way) `NSString` uses UTF-16 internally so there might be a slight performance gain because it does not have to do a UTF-16 <-> UTF-8 conversion. Personally, we prefer (as @gnasher729 suggests) robustness over performance and use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: macOS and my app are not running on big endian cpus, so I prefer utf16.

Answer (score 68):

```
NSString *str = @"helowrld";
// This converts the string to an NSData object
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

you can take reference from this [link](http://albertech.blogspot.in/2011/08/convert-nsstring-to-nsdata-and-back.html)

Comment: One liner solution: `NSData *data = [@"helowrld" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 35):

Do:

```
NSData *data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then feel free to proceed with `NSJSONSerialization:JSONObjectWithData`.

---

#### Correction to the answer regarding the NULL terminator

Following the comments, official documentation, and [verifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087094/does-converting-nsstring-to-nsdata-force-a-trailing-byte), this answer was updated regarding the removal of an alleged NULL terminator:

1. As documented by [dataUsingEncoding:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416696-datausingencoding?language=objc):

   > #### Return Value
   >
   > The result of invoking `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` with NO as the second argument
2. As documented by [getCString:maxLength:encoding:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415702-getcstring?language=objc) and [cStringUsingEncoding:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstringusingencoding?language=objc):

   > note that the data returned by `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` is not a strict C-string since it **does not have a NULL terminator**

Comment: This is WRONG!  Please see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14087094/192819

Comment: Yup. `dataUsingEncoding:` does not return null-terminated data. Only `UTF8String` and other methods that return a C string return a null-terminated string.

Comment: @PeterHosey do you have any source for that? I am having a hard time finding that in any docs.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi: The methods that take or return a C string are expressly documented so; for example: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/UTF8String You can verify this for other methods, such as `dataUsingEncoding:`, by inspecting the data's length and bytes. (Note that some encodings, such as UTF-16, will emit 0x00 bytes! But those aren't terminators; they're part of larger code units. And it is possible to have a U+0000, which will be encoded as such, but is not a terminator.)

Comment: @shortstuffsushi To wit: `const unichar buffer[1] = { 0x0000 }; NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCharacters:buffer length:1]; NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]; NSLog(@"%lu %@", (unsigned long int)data.length, data);`

Comment: @shortstuffsushi And please do file bugs against the docs: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Thanks @PeterHosey, the docs you linked there *do* explicitly state the lack of NULL termination -- `(note that the data returned by dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion: is not a strict C-string since it does not have a NULL terminator)`. I must have missed this earlier. I'll be sure to write up anything in the future, though.

Comment: (For anyone who's wondering: shortstuffsushi's quote is under `cStringUsingEncoding:`. I was looking under `dataUsingEncoding:`.)

Comment: @jpswain the author of the post didn't visit StackOverflow in the past 4 years and the score of the answer is too high for a reversal, so I've made a clear correction directly. Maybe users with 20,000+ reputation could vote to delete the answer, as what is left correct is duplicate information from other answers.

Answer (score 20):

In case of Swift Developer coming here,

to convert from NSString / String to NSData

```
var _nsdata = _nsstring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 18):

**Objective-C:**

```
NSString *str = @"test string";
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:str];
NSString *thatStr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

**Swift:**

```
let str = "test string"
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: str)
let thatStr = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! String
```

Comment: Probably processor-intensive compared to the other methods, but very useful if you're accessing the file system for persistence

Answer (score 10):

First off, you should use `dataUsingEncoding:` instead of going through `UTF8String`. You only use `UTF8String` when you need a `C` string in that encoding.

Then, for `UTF-16`, just pass `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` in your `dataUsingEncoding:` message.

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 3, you will mostly be converting from `String` to `Data`.

```
let myString = "test"
let myData = myString.data(using: .utf8)
print(myData) // Optional(Data)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Objective-C:**

NSString to NSData:

```
NSString* str= @"string";
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

NSData to NSString:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Swift:**

String to Data:

```
var testString = "string"
var somedata = testString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Data to String:

```
var backToString = String(data: somedata!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *str = @"hello";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:str.UTF8String length:str.length];
```

Comment: This answer is wrong when `str` contains code points larger than 127. This is because `str.length` gives the number of Unicode characters, not the number of bytes. For example, if `str` is `@"にほんご"`, `str.length` gives 4 while `str.UTF8String` actually contains 12 bytes. Even if you replace `str.length` by `strlen(str.UTF8String)`, it will still be wrong for the case where `str` contains the NULL character, such as `@"にほ\0んご"`.

Comment: A NSData object created in this way throw exeption when using with [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

Answer (score 5):

Update Swift 5.x

```
let str = "teststring"
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift:**

Swift 5.x

```
let myStringToConvert = "My String to Convert in Data"
let myData = myStringToConvert.data(using: .utf8)
```

String to Data:

```
var myStringToConvert = "My String to Convert in Data"
var myData = myStringToConvert.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Data to String:

```
var backToMyString = String(data: myData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
```

**OBJECTIVE C:**

NSString to NSData :

```
NSString* myStringToConvert= @"My String to Convert in Data";
NSData* myData=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
```

NSData to NSString :

```
NSString* backToMyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"Banana";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:true];
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C

```
NSString *str = @"Hello World";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
```

Swift

```
let str = "Hello World"
let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift there is an API which returns a **non-optional**

```
let str = "teststring"
let data = Data(str.utf8)
```