# iPhone parsing of XML data, Tags not appearing

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I am facing a peculiar problem in parsing some xml data within my iPhone application. When I pass the xml data to NSXMLParser class for parsing, it ignores the part where the actual data starts appearing. It shows all the element names just before the data appears such as Soapenvolopebody etc. Later, I observed that the tags are appearing with '&lt'; and '&gt';symbols which is causing the problem.

I hope this requires a replacement strategy before parsing it to NSXMLParser. My questions is why iPhone is taking XML in that way? I am generating xml dynamically from a php file and comes as an XML when loaded into IE Browser. Hope you can help me to resolve the issue.

> Update

I am still looking for a solution. I think the the idea of converting NSString to NSData and then passing it to NSXMLParser could accomplish parsing.

NSString* str= @"teststring";
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
I found this mentioned in the following post which I will be trying out. [How do I convert an NSString value to NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901357/how-do-i-convert-a-nsstring-value-to-nsdata)

> Update 1

I get the data in NSData format. Converted to NSString and applied replacement code to done away with &lt and &gt stuff. After that, I again converted the replaced NSString to NSData format. But still the xml is not correctly parsing using NSXMLParser.

Comment: can you give me the xml file data and i will give u a xml parsing working code for u r xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please replace the unwonted character using this string function. please refer the below code.

```
NSString *theXML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webdata mutableBytes] length:[webdata length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];

theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];

NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
```

Thanks