# Does converting NSString to NSData force a trailing byte?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is in response to this incorrect answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7894952/192819

Does converting NSString like this:

```
NSString *str = @"teststring";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

force a trailing \0 byte, which means

```
-[NSJSONSerialization:JSONObjectWithData:]
```

and others will fail unless you remove it.

Comment: Ha! You've certainly gotten plenty of rep from what, is, essentially, an extended comment (that happened to fit nicely into a Q&A format) in response to an incorrect answer. Well, I won't begrudge you it. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, it does not.  See this example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"v1", @"k1", 
                      @"v2", @"k2",
                      nil];
NSLog(@"dict=%@", dict);

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];    

NSString *jsonAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *jsonDataFromString = [jsonAsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// DO NOT DO THIS:
// jsonDataFromString = [jsonDataFromString subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [jsonDataFromString length] - 1)];

NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonDataFromString options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@", jsonObject);
```

Try it, and then try it with the "DO NOT DO THIS" line uncommented.  You will see there is no problem.

Comment: So nice to see people answering their own questions again.

Comment: @CodaFi is it a bad thing?

Comment: No, in fact, it's encouraged under the FAQ.  It's just that some people see it as cheating and start downvoting like mad when it happens.

Comment: I would have hoped that since I posted it specifically to correct a totally incorrect answer in another question that would not be considered a bad thing.  Bummer.