# Multipeer Connectivity - Use with a pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity, pin-code

I want to use the new iOS 7 [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328-CH1-SW1) in my app where one person is a host, and anyone can join the host.

I have successfully implemented it using a combination of this [tutorial](http://techmaster.vn/2013/09/multipeer-connectivity-quick-tutorial/) and the Apple Developer Reference to Multipeer Connectivity.

What I want to do however, is add an extra layer of security so not just everyone can join the app. I want it so when a person requests to join the host, they must enter a random 4 digit pin code which the host will tell the group so people who know it can type it in and join the session.

Is this possible to do? As iOS 7 is so new, it is hard to find andy information on it.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This absolutely is possible to do. When you invite your peer to connect to the service, you can send an NSData object to the advertiser. Just [convert the pin code to an NSData object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901357/how-do-i-convert-an-nsstring-value-to-nsdata) and send it to be checked on the advertising device.

You can find the relevant info on [Apple's documentation site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceBrowserClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCNearbyServiceBrowser/invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:), with the `context` variable. Let me know if you need more guidance.

```
- (void)invitePeer:(MCPeerID *)peer
         toSession:(MCSession *)session
       withContext:(NSData *)context
           timeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Thanks very much for the response! I did discover that in my research. I have tried to implement it using the WWDC multipeer connectivity video. My code is:

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Thanks very much for the response! I did discover that in my research. I have tried to implement it using the WWDC multipeer connectivity video. My code and full question are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486762/sending-and-receiving-an-invitation-with-multipeer-connectivity
You obviously seem to have a pretty good grasp of the whole framework so some help would be much appreciated! Thanks :)