# iOS : How do i convert NSString to NSMutableData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledata

I am trying to convert my `NSString` to `NSMutableData` without the use of `encoding`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: how do you mean _without encoding_? what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: An `NSString` internally used UTF16 but I doubt you want those bytes. Thus what encoding do you want? What if the string contains an Å or even a ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSString to \`NSMutableData\` in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023987/convert-nsstring-to-nsmutabledata-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
NSString *str = @"grazz";
NSMutableData *data1 = [[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
NSMutableData *data2 = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[str UTF8String] length:[str length]];
```

ps: I'm not sure about *"without encoding"*, what did you mean by that?

Comment: respecting your efforts sir. i think your answer will helps later.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out here: [NSString value to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901379/820519), you can use `dataUsingEncoding` to convert an `NSString` to `NSData`.

To place it in a `NSMutableData` container, simply make a `mutableCopy`, like so:

```
NSString *string = @"MyString";
NSMutableData *mutableData = [[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
```

As for doing this "without the use of `encoding`", the string will always be encoded. Even if you don't set any specific `encoding` the string will still be encoded. I think the solution above should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

why the question is downvoted?

```
NSString* str = @"teststring";
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *yourdata = [data mutableCopy];
```

first you have to convert to `NSData` and then to `NSMutableData`. From my knowledge, we cannot convert directly to `NSMutableData` from `NSString`.

Comment: i think it'll help you