# Convert string to mutable data - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsmutabledata

How to convert a string into mutable data in objective c

Comment: First, convert NSString to NSData and then, NSData to NSMutableData

Comment: Convert NSData to NSMutableData 

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:jsonData];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
NSString *str = @"any string";

NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *mutableData = [data mutableCopy];;
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can convert NSString to NSData by using

```
NSString* str = @"mystring";
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *yourdata = [data mutableCopy];
```

hope it helps you :)