# NSString to NSAttributable String with multiple links

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, nsstring

I have the following NSString:

```
NSString *example = @" I like cheese and ham and eggs, but ham more than cheese and cheese more than ham!";
```

I'd like to change this into an NSAttributable string so that I can output this in a UITextView where cheese becomes a hyperlink to www.cheese.com and ham becomes a hyperlink to www.ham.com

Is this at all possible?

Matt

Comment: Why so many related questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an NSString value to NSData?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901357/how-do-i-convert-an-nsstring-value-to-nsdata)

Comment: @MaxPoshusta That's not even close to this question.

Comment: In case you're using `UITextView` because you thought that was the only way to do it, I thought I should mention it's possible to do this with a [UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29352519/168594).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. I have just manually calculated the range for the string. But you can make it automated. Its just a example.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I like cheese and ham and eggs, but ham more than cheese and cheese more than ham!"];
[str addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.cheese.com"] range: NSMakeRange(6, [@"cheese" length])];
tempTextView.attributedText = str;
```

And then use below delegate method to get action :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)url inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```