# How to convert a sting to a date, and back again, in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I receive a timestamp from a JSON request, and I want to format it to a user-friendly format. Both the input, as the desired output are of type 'String'.

The format of the input timestamp is: `2020-03-07T12:18:26.347Z`

Using the following code, I try to convert it to the desired format. But it will just output the value of `Date()`, indicating that the output of `formatter.date(from: date)` is `nil`.

What am I missing?

```
func convertDate(date: String) -> String {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "d-M-y, HH:mm"

    let convertedDate = formatter.date(from: date) ?? Date()

    return formatter.string(from: convertedDate)

}
```

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-convert-dates-and-times-to-a-string-using-dateformatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with it for hours, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901357/how-do-i-convert-an-nsstring-value-to-nsdata?rq=1), together with the date format information found [here](https://nsdateformatter.com), I figured it out. I did previously not describe to the dateformatter how the input string would look.

```
func convertDate(date: String) -> String {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    // This is important - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if the format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

    //`date(from:)` returns an optional so make sure you unwrap when using.
    let dateFromString: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy, HH:mm"

    //Using the dateFromString variable from before.
    let stringDate: String = formatter.string(from: dateFromString!)

    return stringDate

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dateFormat doesn't match the format of your input string. You want something like:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```